# how to display json content in li format in phonegap

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, cordova

i can get the json in the following format

```
[{"data":{"id":"1","user_name":"StudentA","book":"123","role":"Student"}},
{"data":{"id":"3","user_name":"StudentB","book":"456","role":"Student"}}]
```

how can i use the data to present like the image below, where the first line is username and second line is book

[image: how can i use the data to present like the image below, where the first line is username and second line is book]

```
<button type="button" id="test">Test 123</button>

 <ul id="studentList" data-role="listview" data-filter="true"></ul>
```

```
var serviceURL = "http://mydomain.com/";
var students;

    $("#test").click(function()
    {   
        getStudentList();
    });
function getStudentList() {
    $.getJSON(serviceURL + 'getStudents.php', function(data) {
        $('#studentList li').remove();
        students = data.user_name;
        $.each(students, function(index, student) {
            $('#studentList').append('<li>' +
                    '<h4>' + student.user_name + ' ' + student.password + '</h4>' +
                    '<p>' + student.user_name + '</p>' +
                    '</li>');
        });
        $('#studentList').listview('refresh');
    });
}
```

may i ask if the codes above correct?

Comment: What output do you get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are naming response as `data`..since you response is in array `[]` you have to loop `data` first.. get its object which is data again  ..

```
[{"data":{"id":"1","user_name":"StudentA","book":"123","role":"Student"}},
//-^^^^---here
```

and get the correponding name and password object in the loop...you can get that by `.` operator.. so inside loop, `student.data.user_name` gives you username , `student.data.book` gives you book and similar for others...

try this...

```
$.getJSON(serviceURL + 'getStudents.php', function(data) {
    $('#studentList li').remove();
  //students = data.user_name;
    $.each(data, function(index, student) {
        $('#studentList').append('<li>' +
                '<h4>' + student.data.user_name +'</h4>' +  //here get username
                '<p>' + student.data.book + '</p>' +   //here get book
                '</li>');
    });
    $('#studentList').listview('refresh');
});
```

Comment: this should work if you are getting the response as above json mentioned in the question.. make sure you are getting the response first.....and let me know..

Comment: i didn't see the $.getJSON part in the provided link.. did u miss that??

Comment: i can get the content if i post the html,js files to server side, yet if i check it in the app, nth show

Comment: i guess there is some crossbrowser issues...since the path you provided in getJSON looks like another server/domain

Comment: yes.. i was about to mention  about the jsoncallback ... seeing your previous comment (which you delete i guess :) ).. anyways glad you made it work yourself.. happy coding :)

Comment: sorry, may i ask one more question. do u know how to perform the style like the image shown above? is it simply css?  anyway thanks your great help

Comment: yes.. it is..:)... you can playaround with your css to get that..(though i am not much into CSS).. :)...

Comment: there in example written by bipen - small mistake: missing + after student.data.user_name. But you @hung - just ask somebody solve you problem and you don't try to find or debug & think... every day you write code using stack overflow for you clients? but remember if you not start think by you head - you will never be engineer

Answer (score 1):

I have done it like that based on your input, you just need to include it into your code. I don't know what you mean by 'second line is book' since there is no book included in your json input + you are trying to access 'student.data.password' which is also not present in input.
Simple  version of jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/2KMd9/

```
var json =[{"data":{"id":"1","user_name":"StudentA","book":"123","role":"Student"}},
    {"data":{"id":"3","user_name":"StudentB","book":"456","role":"Student"}}];


    var students = json;
    $.each(students, function(index, student) {
        $('#studentList').append('<li>' +
                '<h4>' + student.data.user_name + '</h4>' +
                '<p>' + student.data.role + '</p>' +
                '</li>');
    });
```

So for your needs:

```
function getStudentList() {
    $.getJSON(serviceURL + 'getStudents.php', function(data) {
        $('#studentList li').remove();

        $.each(data, function(index, student) {
                $('#studentList').append('<li>' +
                '<h4>' + student.data.user_name + '</h4>' +
                '<p>' + student.data.role + '</p>' +
                '</li>');
        });
        $('#studentList').listview('refresh');
    });
}
```